# Consequence of Hensel's Lemma

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The background of the question is following: [About cyclotomic extensions of $p$-adic fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67328/about-cyclotomic-extensions-of-p-adic-fields/67352)

[image]

Let $n$-th root $\zeta_n$ be primitive $n$-th root and $n$ coprime to the prime $p$, then there is claimed that we have an isomorphism $$\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p[\zeta_n]/\mathbb{Q}_p) \cong \text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_p[\zeta_n]/\mathbb{F}_p)$$ between Galois groups by Hensels Lemma.

It's not clear to me why does Hensels lemma imply this isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\Gal{\operatorname{Gal}}\def\FF{\mathbb{F}}\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}\def\NN{\mathbb{N}}$A basic fact of finite fields is that $F=\FF_p(\zeta_n)$ (with $p \not\mid n$) is the splitting field over $\FF_p$ of $f(x) := x^{p^d-1}-1$ where $d \in \NN$ is minimal such that $n \mid p^d-1$. Also every non-zero element of $F$ is a root of $f$, and $(F:\FF_p)=d$, and $\Gal(F/\FF_p) \cong C_d$ is generated by $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^p$.

Let $E=\QQ_p(\zeta_n)$, then clearly its residue class field is $F$. Take any non-zero $\bar\alpha \in F$, it is a root of $f(x)$, and lift it to an element $\alpha \in E$, i.e. such that $\alpha$ reduces to $\bar\alpha$ in the residue class field. Now $f'(\alpha) = (p^d-1)\alpha^{p^d-2}$ and since $v_p(p^d-1)=0$ and $v_p(\alpha)=0$ we deduce that $v_p(f'(\alpha))=0$. Therefore we can apply Hensel's lemma to deduce that there is $\beta \in E$ such that $f(\beta)=0$ and $\bar\alpha = \bar\beta$. Since there were $|F|-1=p^d-1=\deg(f)$ choices of $\bar\alpha$, we have found this many distinct roots of $f(x)$ in $E$, and we deduce that $E$ contains the splitting field over $\QQ_p$ of $f(x)$. Conversely, since $\zeta_n$ is a root of $f(x)$, we see that the splitting field contains $\zeta_n$ and hence $E$. Hence $E$ is the splittng field, and so in particular $E = \QQ_p(\zeta_{p^d-1})$.

If $\sigma \in \Gal(E/\QQ_p)$ then it restricts to $\bar\sigma \in \Gal(F/\FF_p)$. Further, such a $\sigma$ must map $\zeta_{p^d-1} \mapsto \zeta_{p^d-1}^k$ for some $k$. Putting this together, then $\bar\sigma(\zeta_{p^d-1}) = \zeta_{p^d-1}^k$, but the only elements of $\Gal(F/\FF_p)$ can have $k=p^j$. We deduce that $\Gal(E/\QQ_p)$ is cyclic and generated by the automorphism $\zeta_{p^d-1} \mapsto \zeta_{p^d-1}^p$, just like $\Gal(F/\QQ_p)$ and so they are naturally isomorphic, the isomorphism being $\sigma \mapsto \bar\sigma$.

Comment: I can see that $\sigma \mapsto \bar\sigma$ is surjective (it is a special case of the statement for Dedekind domains), but why is it injective? I.e. why does $E/\mathbb Q_p$ have degree $d$ (and not larger)? Thanks!

Comment: The last paragraph of my answer shows that any $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is of the form $\zeta_{p^d-1} \mapsto \zeta_{p^d-1}^{p^j}$, and there are $d$ possible values for $j$ (since $\zeta_{p^d-1}^{p^d} = \zeta_{p^d-1}$ only $j \bmod d$ counts) and so the Galois group is cyclic of order $d$, generated by $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^p$.

Comment: I figured it out, I was missing the fact that all $\zeta_{p^d-1}^k$ are distinct in $\overline {\mathbb F_p}$ (for $k <p^d-1$) - it is somewhat tatuological -
 so that we can recover the exponent after reducing mod $p$.

Comment: @Doris: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer. One point stays unclear to me: That's clear to me that every root $\bar{\alpha}$ of $f$ in $F$ can be lifted to a root of $f$ in $E$ (by Hensel), but does this already imply that $E$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$? For example maybe $E$ could be **bigger** than the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or not every root $r$ of $f$ could be contained in $E$.

Comment: Indeed, by reducing to $F$ the image $\bar{r}$ of $r$ is in $F$ and it can be lifted to the root $s \in E$ with $s = r \ mod \ p$, but ig $r \neq s$... or did I overlooked an argument?

Comment: By definition $E=\mathbb Q_p(\zeta_n)$ and $\zeta_n$ is a root of $f$, so the splitting field contains $E$. Hence they are equal. I have edited the answer to reflect this.